# why my leaflet map Keep showing blank areas

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, gis

i have this problem that my map with leaflet that some areas appears blank in grey color
sometimes it shows and sometimes it don't .
[image: example image]

my code

```
`const here = {
apiKey:'KIkvbFS6m8sHRe4oFi7YQ_90C8mxPl94dFuLNW4F8uM'
}
const style = 'normal';

const hereTileUrl = `https://2.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/${style}/{z}/{x}/{y}/512/png8?apiKey=${here.apiKey}&ppi=320`;

const map = L.map('map', {
 center: [31.7945, -7.0849],
 zoom: 5,
 minZoom: 5,
 maxZoom: 11,
 layers: [L.tileLayer(hereTileUrl)]
});
map.attributionControl.addAttribution('&copy; HERE 2020');


    var defaultBase =
    L.tileLayer.provider('HERE').addTo(map);

    var baseLayers = {
        'HERE': defaultBase,
        'USGS TNM': L.tileLayer.provider('USGSTNM'),
        'ESRI Imagery': L.tileLayer.provider('Esri.WorldImagery'),
        'ESRI Ocean Basemap': L.tileLayer.provider('Esri.OceanBasemap'),
        'OSM Topo': L.tileLayer.provider('OpenTopoMap')
    };


    L.control.groupedLayers(baseLayers).addTo(map);`
```

Comment: Looks like network errors. Use your browser's developer tools to inspect the network requests relative to the failing tiles.

Comment: @IvanSanchez thanks i found out that problem in the  " const style = 'normal' " it should be const style = 'norma.dayl'

Comment: can you please help me with this   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61297529/how-can-i-show-map-roads-and-cities-on-top-of-an-overlay-image-layer-in-leaflet